How Do I Use A Self-Uploaded Font On A Single Page?
I created a banner on Canva for an FAQ page. I like the font, and now I would like to use it for headers and what not on a single page.
The font is Aloja-Light, and I was able to download it.
I have an otf file, and a woff file, which is apparently what you need for self-hosting a font.
-
I have absolutely no idea about programming, so I started to follow the instructions on here: https://pixelgrade.com/docs/advanced-customizations/fonto-premium-fonts/
BUT I don't know if they're the right instructions for what I need. They seemed easy to follow, but - after uploading the woff file in the folder specified, Media still can't find it and I don't know how to use it on a page anyway.
Any help please?
Thanks x

The Styles editor accessible through Appearance > Themes > (Current theme) > Customize, or Appearance > Editor > Styles > Edit button seem to have controls for uploading a font (or selecting one from Google Fonts)... but I'm struggling to find good documentation on the feature. If you're using a third-party plugin to manage fonts - or your theme has some sort of custom font management solution - you would need to ask in that extension's support channels (or associated/more general communities).
